# Get all commits into a single commit after merge in git

Tags: git

[image]

As you can see in the image above, there is a branch 'fnf1' with sha - '40b1...'
In this commit some code changes were made in file 'A'.
This branch has already been merged with main branch. Now, I want to make some new changes in the code file 'A'.

My main goal is to keep all the changes made in code file 'A' in a single commit.
However, when I make new changes and rebase on the main, the new commit only contains the current change but not the changes made in '40b1...' commit.

What shall I do to get the changes of commit '40b1...' and and new change that I want to make into a single commit?

Comment: You might get them into a single commit by amending 40b1a (or the branch) buf that will create a *different* revision that won't magically become part of the current main branch. Git by definition can't let you do that for security/consistency reasons. So, you might rewrite main on top of the new revision you would be creating.... but, well, I just said it: **you would be rewriting history** (with all its little annoying/burdensome implications that you have to consider if they are worth).

Comment: Once `40b1` was merged into `main`, *every* commit after that has the changes to file `A` in it. So if you make a *new* commit on the tip of the branch, it's starting with those changes already, so you won't be able to get those same changes into a new commit. You could interactive rebase and move `40b1` to next to your new commit (or vice-versa), and squash the two commits together. Knowing this, you may want to think about *why* you want all changes to `A` to be in a single commit?